# A non observant Jew cooks on Shabbos does that treif the kitchen and utensils?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kashrut-kosher

If a non-observant Jew lives in an observant home and cooks on Shabbos in the kitchen. Would that make the kitchen and utensils treif?

Or would he make the kitchen treif by warming up already cooked food?

In both scenarios can the rest of the household eat the food on Shabbos or after Shabbos?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/27521

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=950&st=&pgnum=97

Comment: a non-observant Jew's cooking may be bishul akkum, which would render anything they used to cook foods that are oleh al shulchan melachim and not edible raw treif regardless of Shabbos

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 unrelated parts to this question

1. Hilchos Bishul Akkum
2. Maaseh Shabbes

Regarding eating food cooked by an non observant jew. The פתחי תשובה יו"ד סימן קיב ס"ק א is lenient as there is no איסור to marry such a jew. The כף החיים יו"ד סימו גי"ג ס"ק י"ב argues and cites an opinion which doesn't allow it.
So even if for some reason hilchos shabbes weren't transgressed (i.e. pikuach nefesh) the food would nevertheless be non kosher according to the Kaf Hachaim.

Regarding Maaseh Shabbes, if food was cooked on shabbes by a jew it falls in to the machlokes in orach chaim 318:1 . The mechaber holds that if it was done on purpose others can eat it after shabbes vs. the transgressors who can never eat it. If it was done beshogeg, all can eat it after shabbes. The mishna beruura (7) is more lenient if there is a need to eat it, then if it was intentional all can eat it after shabbes, if it was unintentional everyone can eat it right away.

If the non observant jew only warmed up food, it will depend on many details to see if hilchos shabbes were transgressed, i.e. was liquid involved, where did he warm it up , was it cold, etc. If it was the aforementioned machlokes might apply.